# Setting position for Multiple Label frame in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid

I am using Grid manager to set each of my label frame in rows and columns, after my code run, the middle 2 frame does not appear as what i set in my coding.How can i ensure the middle 2 frame is appear in my program, Regards.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtOZ3.jpg)

```
from tkinter import *

class ConfigureUAinterface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        root.minsize(width=700, height=520)
        root.maxsize(width=700, height=520)
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Grid.config(self)
        #FramePackA:Configuration UA
        self.framepackA =     LabelFrame(master,width=200,height=520,background='red')
        self.framepackA.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=1)
        self.framepackA.grid_propagate(0)
        #FramePackB:DateSelection
        self.framepackB = LabelFrame(master,width=260,height=198,background='grey')
        self.framepackB.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.framepackB.grid_propagate(0)
        #FramePackC:Final Step
        self.framepackC = LabelFrame(master,width=260,height=322,background='light blue')
        self.framepackC.grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.framepackC.grid_propagate(0)

        #FramePackD:Case Suggestion for UA
        self.framepackD = LabelFrame(master,width=240,height=520,background='dark violet')
        self.framepackD.grid(row=0,column=2)
        self.framepackC.grid_propagate(0)
root = Tk()
root.title("UA Configuration")
cuai= ConfigureUAinterface(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first two lines of your init, you set your maxheight to 520.

Your first row elements (A, D) are at a height of 520.

The second row element (B) can not be displayed as it exceeds the frame limits.

The third row element (D) is not affected by self.framepackC.grid_propagate(0).

**Recommendation**

using grid_propagate(0) is not wrong, but grid_propagate(False) would be much more readable.

increasing max_size to height=1020 would make them visible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion: how if i want frame B and frame C stick together that can have same height as Frame A /Frame D like this:
Which mean i want all Frame A and Frame B+Frame C, Frame D have maximum height 520

Here is the link to the screenshot of system: http://imgur.com/si2xFlZ

Comment: I do some modification in my code:
ABD should in row 0.
C should in row 1, but how can i make the C use that empty space in row 0,column 1, Regards

Comment: OK i find the solution is add rowspan=2 in A and D

Comment: If it fixed your problem, please accept the answer so other users know that it worked.